# VisualForce Deploy Error : Open quote is expected for attribute "value" associated with an element type "apex:inputFile"

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

This is my visualforce markup

```
    <apex:form id="importForm">
      <apex:pageBlock>
          <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputFile value=”{!csvInput}” accept=".csv" disabled="{!enableFileInput}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value=”Import” action=”{!readCsvInput}”/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

I get this error while deploying the page

```
Open quote is expected for attribute "value" associated with an  element type  "apex:inputFile"
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word, Outlook or something like that tried to be helpful and screwed up your quotes. They need to be straight `"`, not fancy hipster `”`

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/smart-quotes-in-word-702fc92e-b723-4e3d-b2cc-71dedaf2f343

Comment: Thanks, In this case it was apex intellisense